# PowerMockito. Mock static method. why does not PowerMockito#stub work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, stubbing

I want to mock only one static method in class, all other methods should work like real object.

code:

```
public class ArrTest {

    public static int myMethod (int arr []) {           
        return 777;
    }
}
```

test for this method:

```
public class ArrTestTest {
    @Test
    public void myMethodTest(){        
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(ArrTest.class, "myMethod")).toReturn(0);
        System.out.println(ArrTest.myMethod(null));
    }
}
```

in output I see 777 but I want to see 0;

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you're missing the annotations to make `PowerMockito` instrument the class, and to use the appropriate test runner:

```
@PrepareForTest(ArrTest.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ArrTestTest {
    @Test
    public void myMethodTest(){
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(ArrTest.class, "myMethod")).toReturn(0);
        System.out.println(ArrTest.myMethod(null));
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

To address the followup question in the comments - if you already have a test runner and cannot use `PowerMockRunner`, you can use the `PowerMockRule` to achieve the same result:

```
@PrepareForTest(ArrTest.class)
public class ArrTestTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @Test
    public void myMethodTest(){
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(ArrTest.class, "myMethod")).toReturn(0);
        System.out.println(ArrTest.myMethod(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I do if class ArrTestTest has already RunWith with MockitoJUnitRunner.class ?

Comment: An alternative approach is to use `PowerMockRule` - I've edited my answer with this information too.